# Update nested data state in react native hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I do have a data set in the state of react native. I want to update some nested data and also append some data to the list of the object keys. For example:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    set1: {current_page: 1, last_page: 2, data: [data1, data2, data3, data4]},
    set2: {
      current_page: 1,
      last_page: 4,
      data: [data11, data22, data33, data44],
    },
    set3: {
      current_page: 1,
      last_page: 5,
      data: [data12, data22, data32, data42],
    },
    set4: {
      current_page: 1,
      last_page: 2,
      data: [data11, data21, data31, data41],
    },
  });
```

This is my sample data type.
Later I want to update only a single data key-value pair from the state like for the set2 key I want to set the current_page = 3 and last_page =5 and append the other few data to the data field from another list data. I don't want to affect any other data in the state. I want to update to:

```
let dataToAppend = [data55, data66, data77];
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    set1: {
      current_page: 1,
      last_page: 2,
      data: [data1, data2, data3, data4],
    },
    set2: {
      current_page: 3,
      last_page: 5,
      data: [data11, data22, data33, data44, data55, data66, data77],
    },
    set3: {
      current_page: 1,
      last_page: 5,
      data: [data12, data22, data32, data42],
    },
    set4: {
      current_page: 1,
      last_page: 2,
      data: [data11, data21, data31, data41],
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
setData({ ...data, set2: {...set2, current_page: 3, last_page: 5, data: [...set2.data, ...newItems]} })
```

Comment: I might update the current_page and last_page by this but how can I append/push data to the data list inside the set2 object?

Comment: same way, using spread op, check the updated answer

Comment: Is it possible to insert dynamic field name instead of set2 in above answer. for example if I store let tabName='set2'; can I replace with setData({ ...data, tabName: {...tabName, current_page: 3, last_page: 5, data: [...set2.data, ...newItems]} })

Comment: Yes you can use dynamic name using brackets: ...[setName]: {...}

Answer (score 0):

You could always copy `data` into a local variable, modify properties you need and set `data` with new value. Something like:

```
let result = Object.assign({}, data); //<-- deep copy of data
result.set2.current_page = 17;
result.set2.last_page = 23;
result.set2.data.push(data43);
setData(result);
```